# React-query useMutation not getting executed on Formik onSubmit

Tags: reactjs, formik, react-query

I'm currently making use of Formik the following way:

```
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      title: "",
      language: null,
    },
    validate: (data) => {
      let errors = {};
      if (!data.title) {
        errors.title = "Required";
      }
      if (!data.language) {
        errors.title = "Required";
      }
      return errors;
    },
    onSubmit: (data) => {
      setFormData(data);
      addList.mutate(data); <- Not getting executed
      // closeHandler();
      formik.resetForm();
    },
  });
```

The problem is that `addList.mutate(data)` is not getting executed for some reason. I tried removing the `validate` to see if it was a validation issue, but no, it's not the validation.

Am I actually doing something wrong? How to fix this?

Comment: Could you make a codesandbox?

Comment: Sorry, is not clear what is exactly expected behavior. Ok, looks like you not see addList.mutate(data); maybe it changes an array right? but if this is just a method whole inside your react component it not change state of your component, so you have feel that nothing changes, but it method not causes change state effect. How about use useState and check?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev of course, it would look something like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-http-y283rt?file=/src/Home.js

Comment: @DanielL I inserted a console.log in your addList function and i'ts being called. I just noticed you are doing "storeList = ({ values })", but it's passed as "api.storeList(data)", so there is no values variable there (you are destructuring). I'm not sure if that's your problem, but try to change it to storeList = (values) in your api.js file

Answer (score -2):

Try with `async/await` and try [devtools](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/devtools) for debugging. Ex.

```
try {
  const todo = await mutation.mutateAsync(todo)
  console.log(todo)
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error)
} finally {
  console.log('done')
}
```